# Adding "SITE_ID = 1" Error

Tags: django

Alguien sabe como solucionar este error en ***Django***

> You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the
>   SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID
>   setting to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner en el archivo de configuración:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework